# Form of the optical theorem in non-Abelian theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, yang-mills, s-matrix-theory, scattering-cross-section

I am studying chapter 16.3 from Peskin & Schroeder and I am trying to follow through the argument where we include contributions from ghosts to satisfy the Ward identity in non-Abelian gauge theory. Now I understand the computations done to find the **fermion-anti-fermion $\rightarrow$ 2 gauge bosons** amplitudes. Furtheremore, we see that there is a term in our computation of $$i\mathcal{M}^{\mu\nu}\epsilon^*_\mu\epsilon^*_\nu$$
which doesn't cancel out. Specifically, that term is given by
$$
\bar{v}(p_+)(ig\gamma_\rho t^c)u(p)\frac{-i}{k^2_3}\epsilon^*_{1\mu}gf^{abc}k_1^\rho k_1^\mu
$$
In section 16.3 the authors make use of the optical theorem to show that a contribution from the ghosts cancels this out. The imagenary part of the diagram shown in figure 16.6 (left) is given by
$$
\frac{1}{2}i\mathcal{M}^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\rho}g_{\nu\sigma}i\mathcal{M}'^{\rho\sigma}
$$
where $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{M'}$ the amplitudes of fermion-fermion annihilation and two gauge bosons to fermion-antifermion respectively. My question is, shouldn't there be integrals here? Even though I went through the discussion in chapter 7.3 I'm not quite sure how to apply this here.

Comment: Peskin and Schroeder does say "integrated over the phase space of two massless particles" at the beginning of page 516.